# JDeveloper 11 with Integrated Weblogic Server - Run application NOT on Default Domain

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper 11 with Integrated Weblogic Server 10.3.

I have two applications,one which runs off the default domain and another which I want to run off another domain.

However I can only seem to run off the default domain. When I go into application properties there is no option to change the domain directory integrated web logic server points to.

Comment: are you okay with copying your entire app into your other WLS?

Comment: May you please provide your solution you found?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you have an additional *external* WLS domain outside of JDev and you want to target one app to the Integrated WLS and another app to the external WLS?

If so, you can create a New Deployment Profile for the 2nd app

> Deploy > New Deployment Profile > Application Server Connection

and follow it on.

See page 14 of [linked PDF](http://www.technicalconferencesolutions.com/pls/caat/caat_utility.display_document?conference_id=87&abstract_id=82&document_id=257496&display_context=INTERNAL&z=4873)

Comment: This question is not same as my problem but thanks for pdf. It solved my problem.